# Maven Failsafe Plugin runOrder

Tags: maven, maven-failsafe-plugin

How can I run the integration-tests using specific runorder using maven in command line. I know we can specify the runOrder in pom.xml as `<runOrder>reversealphabetical</runOrder>` but how can I do that in command line. I tried using this command 
`mvn clean integration-test -Dfailsafe.runOrder=reversealphabetical` but looks like it is not working. I don't see my IT tests in reverseralphabetical in target/failsafe-reports file. Is the above mvn command correct for changing the runOrder?

Comment: Please show your pom file ...

Comment: `<plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.17</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <goals>
              <goal>integration-test</goal>
              <goal>verify</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>`